# transitioning to ios8 parse issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, xcode6

I am moving my app from xcode 5 to xcode 6 (sdk 8.0) and the entire app is crashing from random parse errors.

I have searched stack and other sites for answers, but most are just saying missing an @end or a bracket but with my code I am not noticing it.

Here is an example of some code erroring out below:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UITabBar (FlatUI)

- (void)configureFlatTabBarWithColor:(UIColor *)color; UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR
- (void)configureFlatTabBarWithSelectedColor:(UIColor *)selectedColor; UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR

- (void)configureFlatTabBarWithColor:(UIColor *)color
                       selectedColor:(UIColor *)selectedColor;

@end
```

Here is a pic of that same code with the IDE errors:

[image: XCODE 6 Errors]

Many other files have the exact same error. Any pointing to the issue would be appreciated. I have just updated to Xcode 6 and have been pulling my hair out.

Thanks

Comment: The semicolon should be after `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`, not before.

Comment: Looks like you're using FlatUIKit. Did you update it? https://github.com/Grouper/FlatUIKit/issues/151

Comment: It actually was FLATUIKIT that was breaking the entire thing including errors in the app delegate and other stuff. Thank you @ChrisH

Comment: Yep, the referenced update confirms what I stated. The semicolons were in the wrong place.